# How to send POST request to running ACI instance of Docker container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I have a running Azure Container Instance (ACI) based on a Docker image with a single port exposed. The container instance is an API that accepts basic JSON requests and returns a JSON response. I am currently unable to get a response from the ACI.

I am using Postman to send test POST requests. Currently, I am not getting a response. I heard there may need to be some keys/values in the headers, but I'm not sure what those keys would be. I'm also wondering if there's anything else I need to know (e.g. anything I need to prepend or append to the fully-qualified domain name of the container).

I would expect to see a JSON response if the request was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to send POST requests to the Docker API hosting on ACI. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#cannot-connect-to-underlying-docker-api-or-run-privileged-containers), note that

> Azure Container Instances does not expose direct access to the
>   underlying infrastructure that hosts container groups. **This includes
>   access to the Docker API running on the container's host and running
>   privileged containers.**

If you require Docker interaction, check the [REST reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/) to see what the ACI API supports. If you're meant to know how to call Azure REST API with the postman, you can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) and the [step-by-step blog](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-rest-apis-postman/).